# How do I know a xamarin application has push notifications?

Tags: xamarin

I have started to work in a xamarin application. It has not been developed by me. How do I know this application has push notifications?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android check the AndroidManifest to see whether C2DM/GCM/FCM has been set up. Usually this would be several permissions having to be added for this to work.

Similarly on iOS the Info.plist/Entitlements.plist will need to include push notifications capabilities and there will also be implementation of the receiving part in the AppDelegate class.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron. It helped me